# Deploy custom workflow which has service task

Tags: class, deployment, workflow, alfresco, activiti

I have created custom workflow and successfully deployed it on Alfresco.

I just copied my:
myProcess.bpmn.xml, myProcess-context.xml and myProcess-model.xml file into \Alfresco\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\extension folder and 
share-config-custom.xml and .properties in web-extension folder.

That all works fine, process is there, and i can run it.

The problem occurs when i add to my process some service task which reference to some custom java class, i don't now where to put that class? Basically i supposed to need to create some project in eclipse and create some .jar files and deploy on that way my custom workflow, not on this way manually. Does anyone have some idea or example how structure of this eclipse project needs to look like and where this .jar sholud be deployed?

Regards,
Aleksandar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the classes/jars into:

```
YOUR_INSTALLATION/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib
```

I think that should work...

Comment: This is solution, thanks on your help. :) I already copied before on this spot without effect. Anyway, the problem was in my .jar file. I was creating it with Activiti Eclipse plug in, and this doesn't work, .jar file is bad. After your post i created .jar manually and deploy it, and service task runs now ok. :)